# Why are 2 Adobe Flash Plugin on USC (Ubuntu Software Center)?

Tags: flash, software-center, adobe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [flashplugin-installer vs. flashplugin-nonfree vs. adobe-flashplugin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15408/flashplugin-installer-vs-flashplugin-nonfree-vs-adobe-flashplugin)

As you know in Ubuntu Software Center is 2 times Adobe Flash Plugin. One is called Adobe Flash Plugin and other Adobe Flash Plugin 10. Which of the two to install? Or rather it is the recommended installation methods? If we think well, we can install the Adobe Flash plugin for Firefox from the notification date (Install missing plugin) or walking on the Adobe website and downloading the package .deb. After all, how to properly install Flash Player on Linux Ubuntu? (But my biggg question is why are 2 Adobe Flash Plugin on USC? ...for what? If you click on "More Info", the description are the same for both)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the packages you are seeing is a transitional package, `flashplugin-nonfree`. This was the name for flash in the repository for a long time. At one point the Adobe Flash plugin was renamed to something else, `flashplugin-installer`. I don't remember the reasons for this happening. The older package depends on the newer one to make upgrades smoother for people so that if you had installed `flashplugin-nonfree` in the past you would have the proper `flashplugin-installer` when you upgraded.

In 10.10 there's only `flashplugin-installer`. Ideally the Software Center should only be presenting one option to the user, so that's probably a bug. Choosing either one will do the right thing. The prompt in Firefox installs `flashplugin-installer`, so if you just choose that you'll be fine.

The Adobe website gives me the option of a .deb and "APT for Ubuntu 9.04+". The apt option just activates the partner channel in the Software Center and installs the right one anyway. (It's the same package!) I am not sure if the .deb automatically installs their repository to get updates, so it's probably the least desirable of the three.