# flashplugin-installer vs. flashplugin-nonfree vs. adobe-flashplugin

Tags: flash

When searching through Synaptic for flash player I always see the options to use "flashplugin-installer" or "flashplugin-nonfree" or "adobe-flashplugin".  Is there a reason to use one over the other?

I seem to be constantly running into problems with Flash player freezing crashing, mostly because of running too many flash apps at once (pandora/fantasy apps/youtube/etc). Does using one of these over the other have performance benefits?  Or am I confusing myself and it doesn't really matter as they're both the same?

Comment: Notice that there is also the "adobe-flashplugin" package...

Comment: right, I'll add that to the question

Comment: it usually works for me...if it fails for some reason, you can copy the requisite .so files to appropriate directories.. examples include /usr/lib/firefox/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so

Comment: /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
/usr/lib/iceape/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so
/usr/lib/iceweasel/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so
/usr/lib/libvisual-0.4/morph/morph_flash.so
/usr/lib/midbrowser/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so
/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so
/usr/lib/openoffice/basis3.2/program/libflashli.so
/usr/lib/xulrunner/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so
/usr/lib/xulrunner-addons/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so
/usr/share/ubufox/plugins/libflashplayer.so

Comment: the adobe flash plugin has a gtk based GUI for setting individual website options, very much needed case others wont show options when accising camera and mic , u can fix this with adobeflash-plugin by manually adding that site

Comment: [duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49298/whats-the-difference-between-flashplugin-installer-and-adobe-flashplugin) with a better answer!

Comment: I agree with @sarveshlad. I had to use a Flash based video/audio chat and the website didn't asked me if I want to allow webcam/microphone, so the app was not working. This can be configured in the application "Adobe Flash Player Preferences" but it was not installed with flashplugin-installer package. I had to install adobe-flash-properties-gtk that depends on adobe-flashplugin http://askubuntu.com/questions/90783/where-is-the-adobe-flash-player-settings-manager

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*flashplugin-installer* is the 'new' name for *flashplugin-nonfree*. The aim being to more accurately reflect the contents of the package - the package doesn't contain the actual flash player, only an installer that automatically downloads and installs a copy of the plugin. (The file downloaded is the tarball as provided on the Adobe website, but in this case the file is mirrored on Canonical servers.)

The reasons you still see *flashplugin-nonfree* in Synaptic is for backwards compatibility. It is a transitional metapackage with no actual content, all it does is depends on and install *flashplugin-installer*.

So to cut a long story short, there is absolutely no difference between the *flashplugin-installer* and *flashplugin-nonfree* packages.

---

As for the *adobe-flashplugin* package - this is provided in the Canonical Partners repository. The difference with this package is that it actually contains the non-free flashplugin itself (it's not just an installer). Note that this package is exactly the same file as can be installed by downloading from the [Adobe website](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/).

---

So I'm afraid I can't say definitively whether you'll see any performance difference between the *flashplugin-** packages and the *adobe-flashplugin* - but at the end of the day they are the same plugin so it's very unlikely.

Comment: One is just as terrible as the other :)

Comment: I need to clarify that the flashplugin-installer postinst script actually downloads the very plugin from archive.canonical.com not the Adobe web site.  In other words, the "original" upstream tarball of the plugin is downloaded by the flashplugin-installer package.

Comment: @Daneil Thanks I've incorporated that into my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  This has been something that's been bugging me for years.

Comment: @8128 a difference with adobe-flashplugin is that it comes with the useful configuration tool "Adobe Flash Player Preferences". I didn't have this tool installed with flashplugin-installer http://askubuntu.com/questions/15408/flashplugin-installer-vs-flashplugin-nonfree-vs-adobe-flashplugin#comment1018735_15408

Answer (score 14):

It makes no difference which one you use, `flashplugin-nonfree` is a transitional package - a sort of alias that is kept when, for example, a package name is changed - to keep backwards compatibility.

These are *three* options:

1. The flashplugin-nonfree and **[flashplugin-installer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/flashplugin-installer) [image: Install flashplugin-installer]**
       package

   - They download the flash plugin from adobe and install it. **This is the *default*.**
2. The **[adobe-flashplugin](http://packages.ubuntu.com/adobe-flashplugin) [image: Install Adobe Flashplugin]** package from the partner repositories

   - This version is supported by canonical. It will not be as up-to-date, but more stable. Notice that this is a virtual package. It will download flash, Microsoft fonts and so on. But it doesn't seem to be quite the same as the above. The difference must be tiny though, at the time of writing this, the version numbers differ by only a `-2` at the end.
3. Downloading a [[image: Adobe] .deb package directly from adobe](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/).

   - I don't really see any value in this one,  plus it's not obvious. But if an error message somehow redirects you get.adobe.com/flashplayer you can install it alight. It is the same version as the one in the partner repository.

My thanks to jorge castro and fluteflute.