# Where is the Adobe flash player Settings Manager?

Tags: adobe

I want to allow [midomi website](http://www.midomi.com/) to access my microphone. The only way I know is to access this link http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html . However, that link does not give me a way to save the setting I made, so to no avail.

I wonder if I can find the setting manager on my local Ubuntu system? Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run:

```
me@ubuntu:~$ dpkg -l | grep flash
ii  adobe-flash-properties-gtk             11.1.102.55-0oneiric1                      GTK+ control panel for Adobe Flash Player plugin version 11
ii  adobe-flashplugin                      11.1.102.55-0oneiric1                      Adobe Flash Player plugin version 11
```

you will get list of all your 'flash' packages. This way you will find the exact package name: `adobe-flash-properties-gtk`.

Now, you can find binaries in the adobe-flash-properties-gtk package, by:

```
dpkg -L adobe-flash-properties-gtk | grep bin
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/flash-player-properties
```

So, the answer is: `flash-player-properties` command from the `adobe-flash-properties-gtk` package.

Answer (score 1):

The settings should be autosaved as you change them.

If you want a local version, install `adobe-flash-properties-gtk` from the partner repository, though it also doesn't have a 'Save' button.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work (miraculously).

First, using the web-based flash settings, add the "www.midomi.com" URL to:

- Global Security Settings
- Website Privacy Settings

You can see what I mean by seeing this guys instructions [here](http://www.ironzebra.com/code/42/how-to-get-flash-webcam-to-work-on-ubuntu-linux).

Once you're done doing this, open the midomi website **in a new window**. It is very important that you do this, otherwise the settings may not apply.

---

Now here is the part where it gets weirdly interesting.

On the midomi website, just record anything for about 5-10 seconds. It will then take you to a link where it will say "Nothing found". On this page, look for a link called "Test your microphone" (URL might look like [this](http://www.midomi.com/index.php?action=main.mic_check&from=voice_search_results))

After clicking on this link, it will take you to a sort of test area. Here you can specify which mic you would like to use. After choosing the appropriate mic, you should be able to record something.

This might help anyone trying to connect an external device as a mic (midomi seems to always choose your internal device by default).