# Can you clarify package naming conventions for a beginner?

Tags: package-management, updates, flash

I've just applied an update `flashplugin-nonfree` which when I checked in Synaptic updated `flashplugin-installer`. I checked it out because I wasn't sure at first that it wasn't going to re-install `adobe-flashplugin` which was removed during the installation of `flashplugin-installer` as recommended elsewhere.

My question is why is it shown as `flashplugin-nonfree` in Update Manager, and `flashplugin-installer` in Synaptic? Is it that `flashplugin-installer` is just one part of `flashplugin-nonfree`?

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Linux Mint 18 (Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference between the flashplugin-installer and flashplugin-nonfree packages. As @8128 say :

> `flashplugin-installer` is the 'new' name for `flashplugin-nonfree`. The aim being to more accurately reflect the contents of the package - the package doesn't contain the actual flash player, only an installer that automatically downloads and installs a copy of the plugin. (The file downloaded is the tarball as provided on the Adobe website, but in this case the file is mirrored on Canonical servers.)
>
> The reasons you still see flashplugin-nonfree in Synaptic is for backwards compatibility. It is a transitional metapackage with no actual content, all it does is depends on and install flashplugin-installer.

[Link](https://askubuntu.com/a/15410/253251)

Answer (score 3):

There is no `flashplugin-nonfree` package in Ubuntu repositories.

If you see it, it means you are not using Ubuntu, or you installed some custom PPA.

Comment: Apologies, I should have said I'm using Linux Mint 18, thank you

Comment: Linux Mint is off-topic at this site.