# How to stream video on NBC Sports on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, video, flash, chromium

I am having trouble streaming flash content at https://stream.nbcsports.com in any browser I try on 18.04. I tried using Chrome, Chromium, and Firefox with no luck. It just shows a black video screen this text that says "Loading..."

I installed *flashplugin-installer* per [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15408/flashplugin-installer-vs-flashplugin-nonfree-vs-adobe-flashplugin?noredirect=1&lq=1). I was able to verify I have the latest version of flash running in Firefox via this [test page](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/about/). I made sure to enable flash for the page by clicking the dropdown menu under "Not secure" in the address bar where the https lock icon should have been (come on NBC).

Unfortunately, even with flash installed with the latest version and enabled, the video still indicates "Loading..." for all eternity. Do folks have any suggestions for how this problem can be alleviated?